# Why does Unity (DI) work in the Controller, but not in my service layer?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I've used quite a few different `DI` containers in the past, but never Unity (Specifically `Unity 4.0.1`).

I'm working with a plain old `.NET MVC` app with typical 3 tier architecture. `Repository -> Domain -> WebUI`.

I need to know what I am doing wrong so that I can get my registered dependencies to work on the domain layer. Here is what I have in my `global.asax`.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // ...

    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    RegisterDependencies(container);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WebApplicationDependencyResolver(container));
}

protected void RegisterDependencies(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
}
```

Here is the `WebApplicationDependencyResolver` used above:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Infrastructure
{
    public class WebApplicationDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IUnityContainer _container;
        public WebApplicationDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `Domain Layer` class `CustomerService.cs` (which I used both in it's own project and in a folder in the main project):

```
namespace WebApplication1.Services
{
    public class CustomerService
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

        public CustomerService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _uow = uow;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to call the `CustomerService` class in my controller like so, it doesn't work:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var service = new CustomerService();
    return View();
}
```

But If I use the resolver on the controller itself, it works:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public HomeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var service = new CustomerService(_unitOfWork);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Can anyone direct me in the right direction, to get `DI` working on the domain layer?

Comment: there is no constructor that takes 0 parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try injecting the service in the controller instead of injecting `IUnitOfWork`. Then use the service instance in the controller methods:

```c#
public HomeController(CustomerService service)
{
  _service = service
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = _service.GetAllCustomers();
  return View(model);
}
```

This should work, but it is not a good idea to have your class depend on another class. **A dependency should be a contract (interface)**. You should refactor `CustomerService` to extract an interface `ICustomerService` and inject that one instead in the controller. Then you need to register it with the container in method `RegisterDependencies`:

```
container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
```

Comment: While this didn't directly answer my question, it did lead to my answer! Really, this is my fault for not saying that I was trying to resolve a dependency from the Repository layer into the Service layer. But what fixed my issue, was that I implemented the DI container solution for the service layer to the webui layer and that resolved the later injection for the repo -> service injection. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. As long as you do not use `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService` anywhere in your code, you're good. To answer your question... I suspect this is how MVC creates new controller instances. There are places in the workflow where the resolver is used behind the scenes. This is called service location. Try to avoid it if you want to do DI correctly.